# Import external JSON-file to MongoDB using nodeJS and mongoose

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

```
1. City.json (json-file) 

    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Bombuflat",
      "state_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garacharma",
      "state_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Port Blair",
      "state_id": "1"
    }
```

How to store the above json data of cities (only once) into mongoDB using nodeJs and mongoose

Comment: What you have tried???

Comment: Please send the API u have tried, we can enhance it.

Comment: by reading.
here's a blog to start with
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-and-nodejs--cms-29527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a post API by passing the body as your JSON and save it to required Mongo DB collection.

All the documents in the Mongo DB will be saved as JSON.

I hope you are new to node js and mongo db.
Please go through nodeJs documentation and Mongo DB documentation.

This will help you to write your first post API

```
app.post('/city', (req, res) => {
const body = req.body();
City.save(body)
.then(response => {
  console.log('saved to mongo db', response);
  res.json(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error in saving to mongo db', error);
  res.json(error);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Please make City.json file as City.js and use this solution which is right way to do

```
const citites = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Bombuflat",
      "state_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garacharma",
      "state_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Port Blair",
      "state_id": "1"
    }
]
module.exports = citites
```

In routes and where you want to insert. Write this code

```
 const cities = require('./City')
 // db.city.insertMany(cities)  using mongo client 
 // City.insertMany(cities)  using Mongoose
 console.log(cities)
```

**Solution 2**

Please make City.json as array in json file so that we get read hole file and insert docuemnt

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Bombuflat",
  "state_id": "1"
},{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Garacharma",
  "state_id": "1"
},{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Port Blair",
  "state_id": "1"
}]
```

And

```
const fs = require('fs');
let cityData = fs.readFileSync('City.json');  
let cities = JSON.parse(cityData);  
// db.city.insertMany(cities)  using mongo client 
// City.insertMany(cities)  using Mongoose
console.log(cities);
```